# SSH local port forwarding doesn't work, opens a TTY connection instead

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I’m trying to forward a remote port on a server on Digital Ocean to a local port. This is the command I’m using:

```
ssh -R 9000:localhost:3000 root@<server IP>
```

But instead of forwarding the port, this command opens a terminal connection. Is my SSH misconfigured? What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

```
ssh -fNT -R 9000:localhost:3000 root@<server IP>
```

`-fNT` will put ssh in the background, not execute a remote command and disable pseudo-tty allocation.